# My personal hexo theme fails to display the article‘s content completely due to some unknown reasons?

Tags: css, hexo

I have made a hexo theme by myself but when making the post detail page,I found some short posts can display normally while other long posts(maybe 3k words,no so sure)can't display normally-----The extra content has disappeared strangely as well as the bottom section which should have appeared at the bottom all the time.

Normal post：
[image]

Abnormal post:
[image]

Also, I never give the div(which contains a post) a fixed height.